# My scss is not being converted into css when being ran through gulp

Tags: css, sass, gulp

I'm using gulp to converted my SCSS into CSS but whenever i make a new SCSS file while my gulp server is running, the SCSS is not being converted into CSS.

I originally thought it was because the SCSS function was not assigned to the default gulp function but after adding that to gulp.task('default') it still has not worked. I am fairly new to creating my own gulp files and any help would be very much appreciated

```
var gulp = require('gulp');
var sass = require('gulp-sass');
var connect = require('gulp-connect');

gulp.task('connect', function() {
    connect.server({
        livereload: true
    });
});

gulp.task('scss', function() {
    gulp.src('scss/**/*.scss')
        .pipe(sass().on('error' , sass.logError))
        .pipe(gulp.dest('css/'))
        .pipe(connect.reload())
});

gulp.task('html' , function() {
    gulp.src('./**/*.html')
        .pipe(connect.reload())
});

gulp.task('watch' , function(){
    gulp.watch('scss/**/*.scss', ['scss']);
    gulp.watch('./**/*.html', ['html'])
});

gulp.task('default' , ['connect' , 'watch' , 'scss']);
```

I just want my SCSS to be converted into CSS

Comment: What version of gulp are you using?  Run "gulp -v" in the command prompt.

Comment: Please check your source and dest path of gulp file. It should be matched with your folder structure.